# How to remove all the whitespaces from a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've already tried `trim()` but it only removes whitespaces before and after the text. I want something like this.

var str= "This is an example text"

output:

> Thisisanexampletext

Answer (score 83):

Try

```
var str = "This is an example text".filter { !it.isWhitespace() }
```

Answer (score 31):

As suggested by @dimsuz but a little bit more idiomatic with *filterNot*:

```
val string = "f o o b a r b a z".filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }
```

Answer (score 29):

Use

```js
str.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
```

I re-edited @Mark B's answer

Answer (score 10):

```
//Extenion function
fun String.removeWhitespaces() = replace(" ", "")

// Uses
var str = "This is an example text".removeWhitespaces()

println(str)
```

Comment: This only replaces the space character, not whitespace (tab, newline, space, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

```
       var str = "This is an example text".replace(" ","")
```

Comment: That only matches 1 specific type of whitespace character, for example it would not remove tab characters. A better version would be: `.replace("\s".toRegex(), "")`

Answer (score 2):

To remove all unwanted spaces from a string in Kotlin, you could use this function:

```
    fun removeWhiteSpace(menuName: String): String {
        return menuName.replace(" ", "")
    }
```